# Timeout a fetch inside a for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, request, timeout, fetch

I am trying to send several almost identical requests (fetch). The requests themselves should be sent shortly after each other, but not all at once (rate-limit). My current approach:

```
for (let a of alist) {
            a = a.replace(/\s/g, '');  
            sleep(2000).then(()=> {
                fetch(...something with a);
            });
        }
```

All requests are sent about the same time and I get a rate-limit

My sleep-function:

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476626) specifically.

Comment: Currently all your promises are being created at the same time; instead, you should await the `sleep` within the loop.

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured it out :) just had to make a async func